# Update textview using Place Autocomplete's onActivityResult by following MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, autocomplete, onactivityresult

I am trying to set up a dialogfragment with a textview, and once clicked, use an intent to launch the autocomplete activity. When a place is selected, the textview shows the address.

In onCreateDialog, I have the following code

```
binding.dialogLocationText.setOnClickListener {
    val fields =
        listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.NAME)

    val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
        AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields
    ).build(context!!)
    startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Because the textview is accessed through databinding, I can't access it directly in onActivityResult, so created `private lateinit var dialogLocationText: TextView` and `dialogLocationText = binding.dialogLocationText`. Then set text in:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data!!)
            dialogLocationText.text = place.address
        }
        else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
    }
}
```

The above does not look like good practice especially with the redundant reference to the textview, and I'm wondering if I can construct differently to follow MVVM.

Thanks for the help.